# Add new sites on the same level as the parent URL in a multisite

Tags: multisite

My client’s current website resides on example.com

I didn’t read up properly on WP Multisite and installed the new WP and make it Multisite on example.com/site1

Then when I wanted to create the next site within the network, it’s asking me to create in under /site1 sub-directory only. I would like it to be

example.com/site1
example.com/site2

What do I do about this mess?

Unfortunately for me, /site1 has already been fully developed. However, it's also a simple site so it should be easy to just scrape off everything and start over.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks @fuxia for the edit. Do you have any thoughts on my question?

Comment: You can declare `example.com/` as the main site and then add sites under that. Not if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I can't declare example.com as the main site since the Multisite installation resides in example.com/site1